# Google sheets with python

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-apis-explorer, gspread, google-people-api

I have more than 100 google sheets that are shared with a lot of people. I am trying to remove inactive people from the access list. Is there a way in python to extract the list of people who have contributed to the google sheet from the version history?
I used gspread library to access the sheet but not sure how to get the list of contributing users.

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.activity.readonly']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('accessAPI.json', scopes = scope)

drive_service = build('driveactivity', 'v2', credentials=creds)

edit_activities = drive_service.activity().query(body={"filter":"detail.action_detail_case:EDIT", 
                                                       "itemName":"items/xyz",
                                                       "consolidationStrategy":"legacy"}).execute()

# Call the People API
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('accessAPI.json', scopes = scope)

service = build('people', 'v1', credentials=creds)
results = service.people().get(resourceName='people/1080745054',personFields='names,emailAddresses').execute()
```

Running a people ID through people API gives back the below result. It doesn't contain the email address

```
{'resourceName': 'people/1080745054',
 'etag': '%EgcBAj0JPjcuGgQBAgUH'}
```

Is the output being truncated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Approach

Using Python you can achieve this behavior passing through the Drive API and the People API.

1. Get EDIT activity for your google sheets using Drive Activities API
2. Get editors people ids from the `actors` object resource in the Drive Activities API response body.
3. Get editors email addresses from People API with the editors people ids.
4. List all file permissions on you google sheets with Drive API Permissions resource endpoint.
5. Update the permission if the user is not in the editor list according to your logic.

Here is the proposed script in pseudocode:

```
loop your_google_sheets:
    edit_activities = drive_service.activites().query(filter="detail.action_detail_case:EDIT", itemName="items/"+your_google_sheets.id)
    editors = edit_activities.get(actors_ids)
    loop editors:
        editors_emails += people_service.people().get(resourceName=editors.personName, personFields="emailAddresses")
    file_permissions = drive_service.permissions().list(fileId=your_google_sheets.id)
    loop file_permissions:
        update_if_not_editor(editors_email, file_permissions.id) # Implement your own logic
```

### References

[People API get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get)

[Drive Activities API query](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest/v2/activity/query)

[Drive API Permissions list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list)

[Drive API Permissions update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/update)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The activities().query is giving me HttpError. I have updated my code in the problem description.

Comment: Drive Activity API uses different scopes than Drive API. 
 Use `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.activity.readonly"` instead of `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"`

Comment: thanks, that worked. Now I am stuck at people-api response. The output doesn't contain the email address. I have updated the description. Thanks again!

Comment: Always look at the scopes needed to perform an operation in the documentation "Try It" feature. Apparently the scope `contacts.readonly` is not enough to perform this operation. You should be able to make it work with the `userinfo` scopes.

Comment: The "Try it" gives me the detail but not in python. I did try different scopes but nothing helps. It doesn't give me the "name" key. I wonder it is due to accounts not being public. Could that be the reason?
[link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766097/method-people-get-does-not-return-names)

Comment: Yes, it does. It gives me the email address for the account ID

Comment: Ok, then use the same scopes that the "Try it" feature is using and it will work.