# People api of People.get doesn't get names, photos for other user

Tags: api, flutter-web, google-people-api

Dear Google People API developers,

I am using https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get api, but it couldn't get other user information of names, photos and etc., using `resourceName="people/account_id"`.
But I could get my profile information of names, photos and etc when I use `resourceName="people/me"`

I have also tried both web and flutter, it is the same result.

```
{
  "resourceName": "people/110971898718679553920",
  "etag": "%EgYBAgMuNz0aBAECBQc=",
  "photos": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "PROFILE",
          "id": "110971898718679553920"
        }
      },
      "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GgB8WckrOhYHm-R_Y6hugAEu7XxQ-ktNsmzYUQW=s100",
      "default": true
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I get that information?

My code sample as below

Calling people API by library

```
Future<Person> getPersonDetails(String peopleId) async {
    final GoogleAuthClient googleAuthClient =
        await GoogleProvider.provideGoogleAuthClient();

    final PeopleServiceApi peopleServiceApi =
        peopleDataProvider.getPeopleApi(googleAuthClient);

    Person person = await peopleServiceApi.people
        .get(peopleId, personFields: '(names,photos,urls,emailAddresses)');

    return person;
  }
```

Calling People API by HttpClient

```
Future<http.Response> getByPeopleAPI(String accountId) async {

  GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount =
      await GoogleProvider.provideGoogleSignInAccount();

  GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
      await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  http.Client _client = http.Client();
  _client.get(
    Uri.parse(
        "https://people.googleapis.com/v1/$accountId?personFields=names,photos"),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ${googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken}',
    },
  ).then((value) {
    print(value?.body.toString());
  });
}
```

Note: I got people/account_id from google activity API's of actor attribute.

I am looking forward to your support and reply.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Method: people.get() does not return names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766097/method-people-get-does-not-return-names)

Comment: Have you enabled Domain Wide Delegation?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this too in a few parts of the newer People API.  The `people.listDirecory` endpoint seems broken.  The older deprecated `olderContacts.list` works better but is deprecated.

Oddly enough `people.searchDirectoryPeople` works as expected and shows every field in `readMask` but you need to provide a search (no wildcard option apparently). Calling `people.listDirectoryPeople` with exactly the same `readMask` omits most fields.  I'm not sure if there's a different scope required for `people.listDirectoryPeople` or what but it seems there's definitely something wrong with this api as documented - unless someone can point out another doc we're missing somewhere?